# Why does double 'COPY' in dockerfile give error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

For some reason when im building my dockerfile i get this error:

> "Step 9/11 : COPY --from=builder ./usr/src/app/dist /usr/app/dist
>   failed to copy files: lstat
>   /var/lib/docker/overlay2/d16c06f4e33e70fea8e03cfe566fe72a763bd1949b67b64603937758fdf7fe1f/merged/usr/app/dist:
>   not a directory"

However if i comment out one of the 'COPY' it works fine (Doesnt matter which one)
What exactly is going wrong here?

My dockerfile is as following:

```
FROM node:latest as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build:ssr

FROM node:latest
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/package.json /usr/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist /usr/app/dist
WORKDIR /usr/app
CMD [ "npm", "run", "serve:ssr" ]
```

Comment: After the first copy /usr/app is a JSON file, not a directory. You can't create files inside a regular file, so you get the error "not a directory" when you try to create /usr/app/dist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is causing by this line:

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/package.json /usr/app
```

Here, you are copying `/usr/src/app/package.json` into `/usr` directory and naming `package.json` as `app`.

Specify that `app` is not file name. It's a directory. Use following

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/package.json /usr/app/
```